# Huawei E3131 modem shows as mass storage

Tags: 18.04, usb, internet, usb-modem, modem

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and updated the sysytem to the latest. I use Huawei E3131 USB dongle to connect to the Internet. Recently I noticed that the dongle is not detected as a modem. When I run the command `lsusb` it shows as mass storage device.

[image]

I have also installed **usb_modeswitch** on my system.
I searched the Internet but could not find a solution. How to fix this issue to use this device as a modem.

Comment: There are a couple of articles on this, such as http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/ and https://bytefish.de/blog/huawei_e352s5/ How far did you get?

Comment: @Jos Thank you for providing the links. One of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [Jos](https://askubuntu.com/users/149708/jos) I could solve the problem. So I am posting it as an answer.

1. Plug the USB dongle to the computer.
2. Open the terminal and run `dmesg`.

It will show how the device has been detected. In my case it shows as a mass storage device.

[image]

Run `lsusb` to view the vendor and the product ID.

Then install `libusb-xx` if it is not on your system already.
[Download](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/download/v1.0.22/libusb-1.0.22.tar.bz2) tarball and follow the steps on the terminal. Goto the folder where the file was downloaded and run,

```
tar xjf libusb(your_version).tar.bz2
cd libusb(your_version)
sudo make install
```

Then [Download](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/usb-modeswitch-2.5.2.tar.bz2) latest usb_modeswitch tarball and install it.

```
tar usb-modeswitch(your_version).tar.bz2
cd usb-modeswitch(your_version)
sudo make install
```

Follow the same steps to [download](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/usb-modeswitch-data-20170806.tar.bz2) and install usb-modeswitch-data-(your_version).tar.bz2

```
tar usb-modeswitch-data-(your_version).tar.bz2
cd usb-modeswitch-data-(your_version)
sudo make install
```

After that run the below command

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'
```

It will probably correct the problem and should start showing mobile broadband signal. `lsusb` command now shows the device as a modem.

[image]

[Reference](https://bytefish.de/blog/huawei_e352s5/)